# Meson build: How to use compiled library instead of downloading it as subproject and build

Tags: cross-domain, meson-build

I am trying to build gstreamer using gst-build:  h[ttps://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-build](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-build)

Glib is one of the subprojects it is downloading and compile. But I am thinking of replacing it with the previously compiled version. How should I do it in the cross-file? Or there is no way other than hacking meson.build

Thanks
Regrds

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the discovery methods that dependency supports, if it uses pkg-config, it's probably as easy as setting [built-in options]:pkg_config_path in your cross file (or the various $PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variables) to include the pkg-config file. I'm pretty sure that glib uses pkg-config.